# Excel nested IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I'm having trouble with a nested IF function. I want to assign a "T" value to a cell based on its number value between a Max and Min number. The number resides in cells within Column H. However when I nest the function I encounter the #Value! error
Can anyone highlight my flaw?

`=IF(AND(H2>=MIN(8),H2<=MAX(15)),"T-2",),IF(AND(H2>=MIN(0),H2<=MAX(7)),"T-1",)`

Comment: There is a typo in you formula `..., "T-2",),IF(...` should be `..., "T-2", IF(... )` and check your brackets afterwards.

Comment: Note that your `MIN` and `MAX` functions are useless in the manner you are using them. `MAX(n) = n` where `n` is a single number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(H2>=0,H2<8),"T-1",IF(H2<=15,"T-2",""))
```

Comment: Your second `logical_test` will return `TRUE` with negative numbers and => incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter:

```
=IF(H2>=0,IF(H2<=7,"T-1",IF(H2<=15,"T-2")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a good idea to outplace the conditions.

Then you can use this formula

```vb
=XLOOKUP(A1:A6,$C$1:$C$3,$D$1:$D$3,"-",-1)
```

[image]